# c++ function does not take 0 arguments

Tags: c++

Why am I getting [this error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C2660)&rd=true) from the compiler about the function not taking 0 arguments? Is is because I declare the function after it has been called?

```
// HelloWorld.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    cout << "Game over!\n";
    swap();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int swap()
{
    int on = 1;
    int off = 0;
    int temp = on;
    on = off; 
    off = temp;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to declare everything before you use it.

Comment: Avoid `using namespace std` and define a founction with same name...

Comment: It is because you got burned by the `using namespace std;` line in your code.  Guess where the compiler is getting `swap` from?

Comment: Not that your `swap` function will do much of anything anyway. If will just swap the values of two local variables, and nothing outside the function will be affected.

Comment: oh so "swap" is a function that is in the "std" library?

Comment: @JonathanKittell Well, remove `using namespace std;`, use `std::cout`, and see the error that you would have expected.

Comment: ok I remove "using namespace std;" and now see "identifier not found"

Comment: @JonathanKittell -- *Is it because I declare the function after it has been called?* -- Now after you made that change, the answer is now *yes*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is is because I declare the function after it has been called?

Yes.

By the time the compiler sees the call to `swap()`, it doesn't know about your function yet. You'd normally get an error along the lines of “call to undeclared function” in this case, were it not for [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) (which takes two arguments) that you've pulled into your name-space by the `using namespace std` directive.

In order to fix: Move the definition of `swap` *above* `main` (as a function definition is always also a function declaration) or leave it where it is an put a dedicated declaration

```
int swap();
```

above `main`. I'd also get rid of the `using namespace std;` as it, as you can see, might do you more harm than good and instead prefix all standard-library types and functions explicitly with `std::`. But that's not mandatory and also not the root cause of your current issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your function on top of main or Just declare on top of main.It now calls swap from .net library